# vpn and samba together on virtual machine?

Tags: samba, virtualization, vpn, file-sharing

I have got ubuntu 18 installed on a virtual machine. 2 virtual network adapters are connected to machine. 
1 is for internet
1 is for share file with another virtual machine

when I connect ubuntu to a vpn server (special client of a private vpn, not open) over 1st network card,  file share via samba on 2nd network card becomes unavailable. 
Each time when i want to share file, first i have to disconnect the vpn connection.
So, without disconnection from vpn, would it be possible to share files over 2nd network card?

Answer (score 0):

You are routing all your traffic via the 1st networkcard / vpn-server when you connect to your vpn.

You have at least two options now.

1. **Modify the vpn-server-config**

   Chanage your server-config to not bypass your gateway anymore. In OpenVpn this option should be named

   ```
   push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
   ```

   Delete or comment that option
2. **Modify your routing table**

   Don't change the vpn-server config but write a new routing rule. Lets say your samba network is running at 192.168.10.0/24 and your IP in that smb network is 192.168.10.2 you could write a rule like this

   ```
   sudo ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.10.2
   ```

   and the problem should be fixed.